# Passing instance attributes to an object from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, attributes

I have a class `C` with `n` instance attributes `a1, a2, a3, ..., an` and a dictionary

`d = {'ai': x, 'aj': y, 'ak': z, ..., 'be': p, 'bf': q, 'bg': r, ...}`

containing values for some of those instance attributes and some other entries.

An object `O = C()` is constructed. Is there a better way to pass the attribute values that doing

```
O.ai = d['ai']
O.aj = d['aj']
O.ak = d['ak']
```

...
and, so on?

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) help at all?

Comment: @quamrana Not sure if it's related, given the accepted answer. But using `getattr()` might work.

Answer (score 0):

If `C` is a regular class, you can update its `__dict__` directly:

```
class C:
    def update(self, d):
        vars(self).update(d)


c = C()
c.update({'foo': 123, 'bar': 456})
print(c.foo)
print(c.bar)
```

To make your IDE or mypy happy, it would make sense to declare these attributes in the class body or `__init__`:

```
class C:
    foo: int
    bar: int
    ...etc
```

Comment: Does it also work when the dict you're updating with contain some extra keys that aren't instance attributes of C?

Comment: @phydev: sure, those declarations are just for documentation/typechecking purposes, python itself doesn't care.